# Capistrano v3 is trying to load ssh-kit twice and throwing a warning

Tags: ruby, ssh, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

I am trying to capify a project and when I run `bundle exec cap staging -T`
I get a warning

`/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-0.0.34/lib/sshkit.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant SSHKit::StandardError`

`/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-0.0.34/lib/sshkit.rb:3: warning: previous definition of StandardError was here`

and then the output of the command including the list of tasks

`cap deploy                       # Deploy a new release`

`cap deploy:check                 # Check required files and directories exist`

`...`

I have tried removing all the other gems from bundler that would conflict with this but it seems like bundler itself locks this file at versions 2.6.6.  I dont even know if it is bundler causing that problem.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile? Also, try `bundle install --path .bundle` to isolate project's gems from the rest of the system.

Comment: `bundle exec` does isolate gems specified in Gemfile from system ones. No need to do that.

Comment: This was back when capistrano was in beta so I thought it might be that but I am still getting it in version 3.0 and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Current version of `sshkit` is [1.3.0](http://rubygems.org/gems/sshkit). Try running

```
$ bundle update
```

and write if you will still have problems. Sometimes the command:

```
$ gem outdated
```

can be useful for detecting old versions of gems.

Answer (score 0):

It probably a problem related to symlinks inside rvm/rbenv/… it could be resolved avoiding `require_relative` inside the sshkit gem but in the meanwhile I think the only option is stick with the error and wait for [this issue](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/issues/32) to be resolved.